# How to access data-state in div id, cheerio node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am grateful to everyone who participates and will help a newbie.

Task: Access div = client-state, then div = Here-Goes-Some-Div-ID and return json from data-state.

```
<div class="client-state">
      <div id="Here-Goes-Some-Div-ID" data-state='{"items":[{"action":"LAYOUT"}]'>
      </div>
```

I managed to refer to div = client state like this -

```
import cheerio from 'cheerio';

const id = ["98772"]

async function GetDataFunction () {
    try {
        for (let i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
            let HTMLresponse = await ProductSearchFunction(id[i]);
            const $ = cheerio.load(HTMLresponse);

            $('.client-state').each(function()
            {
               const ClientState = $(this).html()
                console.log(ClientState)
            })
        }} catch (err) {
        throw err
    }  
};GetDataFunction()
```

Unfortunately, I did not find information on how to further access the "Here-Goes-Some-Div-ID" div and get data-state=
I would be grateful for the hint, thank you in advance!

Comment: you've put puppeteer as a question tag but your current try is using completely cheerio. are you interested in a cheerio solution or puppeteer is also good for you? in general, make sure that your tags are in alignment with your question.

Comment: David, thx for answer, i'm interested in any, can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with something like this:

```js
await page.$eval('.client-state #Here-Goes-Some-Div-ID', el => el.getAttribute('data-state'))
```

**What's this?**

1. we use the [`page.$eval`](https://pptr.dev/next/api/puppeteer.page._eval/) method to evaluate a specific DOM element
2. the first parameter is the CSS selector for the desired element, you can use a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators#descendant_combinator) - a single space - between the already identified class (`.client-state`) and the HTML id (`#Here-Goes-Some-Div-ID`), [id-s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) are using `#` in front of the id name
3. the second parameter of the function is the so-called `pageFunction` where you can do this: `el => el.getAttribute('data-state')` using [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) on the `data-state` attribute.

You can define it as a variable and then parse its content with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or whatever you want to do with the result.

*Note:* in your current example `'{"items":[{"action":"LAYOUT"}]'` would be unparsable as the wrapper object is not closed with a `}`!

**full example:**

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function main() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  })
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.goto(url)
  const dataState = await page.$eval('.client-state #Here-Goes-Some-Div-ID', el => el.getAttribute('data-state'))
  console.log(dataState)
  console.log(JSON.parse(dataState))

  await browser.close()
}
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's JSON so you have to parse it.

```
let state = $('[data-state']).attr('data-state')
let dataState = JSON.parse(state)
```